# Import signable Certificate on MacOS

Tags: macos, openssl, sign, codesign

I have been trying to import a certificate on MacOS (Monterey).
I managed to convert my `key.pem` and `cert.pem` to a `.pfx` and added it on a Windows machine, and signed a binary using windows's signtool with the pfx file.

When trying something similar on MacOS, it complains that it is the wrong password (and cancel after 3 "failed" attempts).

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -clcerts -inkey key.pem -in cert.pem -out cert_p12.p12
sudo security import macos_p12.p12 -A -k "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
```

I also tried to generate my own certificate, where I simply just set the password to 1234, and add that, but that also failed with the samme password error:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout macos_key.pem -out macos_cert.pem -sha256 -days 365
openssl pkcs12 -export -clcerts -inkey macos_key.pem -in macos_cert.pem -out macos_p12.p12
sudo security import macos_p12.p12 -A -k "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
```

So I don't know what I am doing wrong, so I would appriciate any help!

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue right now. The key won't take the password even though I know it's right.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you have openssl 3+. may be **-legacy** option of pcks12 could help